# Getting error in linking a source folder in eclipse maven

Tags: git, java, eclipse

I created an empty maven project and it created a folder structure `src/main/java`.
Now I want to link source from my local repo to this `src/main/java`.

If I go to `buildpath->link source`, and name the folder as `src/main/java`, I get the **folder already exists error**.
If I delete the folder and then do the same step, I get following error. What is the best way to go forward?

[image]

I cannot change the project structure in the repo location and copying the folder to my workspace would mean manually merging changes later.

Comment: Just an idea, but tried using a backslash (**\**)?

Comment: Backslash, where?

Comment: Instead of the forward slashes in the *Folder name*. I don't have much hope though.

Comment: Ohh. Yes it won't make a difference because when folder is present, it gives folder already exists error.